# Kafka Byte Rate Quota for a client having multiple producers or consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

I had one question on the byte-rate quota management in Confluent Kafka. When we use use config like:

```
/kafka-configs-zookeeper host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181 --alter --add-config
'producer_byte_rate=1024, consumer_byte_rate=2048, request percentage=50' -entity-type clients-entity-name client1
```

I have understood say request percentage is 50 then each will get 50% of the quota window for request handler & network threads

In scenario, If there are 5 applications using the same clientID **client1** for producing & consuming from the cluster, then how would the **producer_byte_rate, consumer_byte_rate & request_percentage** parameter come into play?

1. Would the quota window get uniformly divided into 5 slices of 10%
   each?
2. Would the producer byte rate & consumer byte rate also get
   divided equally among the 5 producers & consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a client ID as a quota group, no matter how many applications are configured with that value, as the official [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotasgroups) says, "*all connections of a quota group share the quota configured for the group*". So, there are no slices of quotas among the applications using the same client ID, and as soon as the quota value has been reached, all applications will get throttled in that quota window.